# Write a program that changes to letters given in an array to '* "in a given string

Tags: python

Write a function that changes letters given in an array to '*' in a given string.

'Irisk' ['i','k'] -> *r * s *

I have tried using:

```
def filter(word, lett):
    new_word = ''
    for c in word:
        if c == lett:
            new_word += '*'
        else:
            new_word += c
    return new_word
```

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) -- don't ask how to solve your homework problem; instead, ask how to solve a narrow, specific technical issue that prevented you from successfully doing your homework yourself. We shouldn't need to work backwards from your in-process code to figure out where you got stuck; the question should make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop to go with "*" or the original letter if the letter is in a list.
Then combine the characters using ''.join().
Like this:

```
my_string = 'Irisk'
my_list = ['i', 'k']
new_string = ''.join("*" if (c.lower() in my_list) else c for c in my_string)
```

Result:

```
'*r*s*'
```

Comment: Good use of  *join* + ListComp.  But the outer `[ .....]` bracket can be skipped/saved.

Answer (score 0):

use 'in' instead of ==

```
def filter(word, lett):
    new_word = ""
    for c in word:
        if c in lett:
            new_word += "*"
        else:
            new_word += c
    return new_word
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use python's built-in `String.replace` method:

```py
def filter(word, letter):
  return word.replace(letter, "*")
```

Comment: Your solution is neat, but only works for single "letters" or "sequence of letters" that you have in the word, i.e. does not handle ['I', 'k'].

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Python builtin string functions - replace

```
  def filter(s: str, c: list) -> str:
      n = s
      for i in c:
          n = n.replace(i, '*')

      return n
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert both `word` and `lett` to lower case when comparing them.

```py
def filter(word, lett):
    new_word = ""
    for c in word.lower():
        if c in "".join(lett).lower():
            new_word += "*"
        else:
            new_word += c
    return new_word
    
print(filter("Irisk" ,['i','k']))
```

Output:

```py
*r*s*
```